# Adsense not showing up, but shown ater page refresh (Chrome & Safari)

Tags: adsense

I have three adsense ads on my page. (It is a Chinese website).

Adsense ads are shown OK if you first view this page. But if you click on the next page link (on the pagination bar), ads do not show up at all. But if you refresh the webpage, they appear normally.

The strange thing is it only happens with Chrome and Safari. No problem with IE & Firefox.

I have searched the internet for a while, but cannot find a solution. The problem has cost me hundreds of dollars per month. Initially I thought the problem was caused by the "Kickstart css framework" I use, but I'm not sure. I have inspected this issue in the Chrome console. The adsense ads give me 400 error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: It is fixed now. The cause is that kickstart framework wraps each div after loading. So that adsense refuse to load request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fixed now. The cause is that kickstart framework wraps each div after loading. So that adsense refuse to load request.